# Can we Add a new layer over CATiledLayer?

Tags: iphone, catiledlayer

I am displaying a big image in CATiledLAyer.

Now i want to draw a line between two points where the user touches on that image.

Would that be possible ?? , if so can you outline me the way to accomplish it ??

Thanks,
Ratna

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for an app a while back.  The strategy I used was to place another view on top of the view with the tiles.  Then set your self up as a UIScrollViewDelegate and everytime the tiled view scrolls or zooms, recalculate where the overlayed objects need to be.  Just read the `contentOffset` value and the zoomScale and you should have what you need to correctly figure out where your overlay needs to be positioned.  You will also have to make sure that touches are correctly reaching the tile view if they have to pass through your overlay view.

Comment: Do you have an example because I am trying to achieve similar kind of app where in which I am trying to add pins like google maps on top of the CATiledLayer.